# Mono AOT compilation - how to get the .so file?

Tags: c#, macos, compilation, mono

I am using Mono on Mac, installed with Unity.

The http://www.mono-project.com/Mono:Runtime:Documentation:AOT page states that mono compiler with aot option should generate .so file.

What I get is a dylib file.

My goal is to generate so file from the managed c# dll file.

Here is the command and output (in terminal):

```
Gerleis-Mac:CrazInvaders gerleim$ /Applications/Unity/MonoDevelop.app/Contents/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.2/bin/mono --aot -O=all iOSBuild/Data/Managed/Assembly-CSharp.dll
Mono Ahead of Time compiler - compiling assembly /Users/gerleim/Desktop/CrazInvaders/iOSBuild/Data/Managed/Assembly-CSharp.dll
Code: 2217337 Info: 87704 Ex Info: 56841 Unwind Info: 80 Class Info: 4663 PLT: 5477 GOT Info: 364454 GOT: 35852 Offsets: 109275
Executing the native assembler: as -arch i386 -W  -o /var/folders/b4/4tgynrr570zd5qdng_4ljs9m0000gn/T/mono_aot_uGBs4E.o /var/folders/b4/4tgynrr570zd5qdng_4ljs9m0000gn/T/mono_aot_uGBs4E
Executing the native linker: gcc -m32 -dynamiclib -o /Users/gerleim/Desktop/CrazInvaders/iOSBuild/Data/Managed/Assembly-CSharp.dll.dylib.tmp /var/folders/b4/4tgynrr570zd5qdng_4ljs9m0000gn/T/mono_aot_uGBs4E.o
Compiled 12759 out of 12761 methods (99%)
2 methods have other problems (0%)
Methods without GOT slots: 8190 (64%)
Direct calls: 716 (20%)
JIT time: 1427 ms, Generation time: 1045 ms, Assembly+Link time: 1712 ms.
```

I guess there are problems with the parameters of the assembler and linker, but I don't have options to change those (see http://mono.wikia.com/wiki/Man_mono)

(When built from the Unity IDE, Unity uses mono and aot and generates .s files for XCode/iOS.)

Answer (score 1):

`.so`s are Linux binaries, so you'd have to compile ahead-of-time on a Linux. When you do this on OS X instead, you get a `.dylib` because that's an OS X library binary. Even if you had a Linux binary on your Mac, it'd be useless to you.